# Anonymous hash in perl

Tags: perl

I am starting to learn Perl, so I am trying to read some posts here at SO. Now I came across this code  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22310773/2173773 (simplified somewhat here) :

```
echo "1 2 3 4" | perl -lane'
  $h{@F} ||= [];
  print $_ for keys %h;
'
```

What does this code do, and why does this code print `4`?

I have tried to study Perl references at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html , but I still could not figure this out.

(I am puzzled about this line: `$h{@F} ||= []`.. )

Comment: The code you posted is not a very good simplification of the code you linked to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The `-n` option (part of `-lane`) causes Perl to execute the given code for each individual line of input.
- The `-a` option (when used with the `-n` or `-p` option) causes Perl to split every line of input on whitespace and store the fields in the `@F` variable.
- `$something ||= []` is equivalent to `$something = $something || []`; i.e., it assigns `[]` (a reference to an empty array) to the variable `$something` if & only if `$something` is already false or undefined.
- `$h{@F}` is an element of the hash `%h`.  Because this expression begins with `$` (rather than `@`), the subscript `@F` is evaluated in scalar context, and scalar context for an array makes the array evaluate to its length.  As the Perl code is only ever executed on the line `1 2 3 4`, which is split into four elements, `@F` will only be four elements long, so `$h{@F}` is here equivalent to `$h{4}` (or, technically, `$h{"4"}`).

Thus, `[]` will be assigned to `$h{"4"}`, and as `4` is the only element of the hash `%h` in existence, `keys %h` will return a list containing only `"4"`, and printing the elements of this list will print `4`.